# Form using PHP & JQuery auto populates fields after form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that uses JQuery AJAX calls while field's are being populated to provide possible matches in the MySQL DB. The JQuery passes the field data to a PHP script that queries the MySQL. I have four separate fields in the form that are making these calls, which are triggered by new characters in the field. The actual effect is that a call is made, and then a DIV is populated by checkboxes for the possible option.

The problem is that after the form is submitted, sometimes the form will be refreshed with one of these DIVs still being populated with the previous checkbox results. My first thought was to clear the $_POST data after every form submission, but this has not resolved it.

Without supplying code, does someone have an idea of why this behavior is happening? I'm super novice, so I'm operating under the idea that this is a n00b problem that is probably related to a misunderstanding of timing of the AJAX request - I.e, the backend is providing input to the new form without realizing the form has been reloaded. I can supply code to show the problem, but I'm currently operating under the assumption that this a common amateur problem that hasn't been resolved by Googling with appropriate search terms. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Browser Cacheing could be causing your issue.

Comment: Can you extrapolate on that? I'm not seeing this behavior on other websites that I visit that have autopopulated forms. I think that it probably has more to do with the AJAX behavior. I definitely don't have anything saying "no thanks" to the AJAX call, and I think maybe I should be saying that in some way?